# How to load javascript file in the success section of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have time picker on my view that is loaded by ajax call. When the view is loaded, the timepicker does not get fully loaded because the javascript file associated with it does'nt load. What i was trying to get some way to load my js on the success method.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  'url': baseUrl...,
  'dataType': 'json',
  'type': 'post',
  'data': {
    formData: formData
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $.getScript(baseUrl + 'resources/....javascriptfile.js', function() {
      jQuery('.div').html(response.html);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is the URL. Those `....` before `javascriptfile.js` are fairly suspect. Your file isn't actually called `....javascriptfile.js`, right?

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: Is the timepicker functionality in the `javascriptfile.js` or how does it associated?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think this is to avoid showing the full real path. The same for `'url' : baseUrl.....`. But we need clarifications about it

Comment: @ PraveenKumar S: jQuery v2.1.4

Comment: you can load a function from a file it would be better than load a whole file in success

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: I have given .... as an example. The url is correct. It is working in other part of the application.

Comment: @user3653474 - I'd suggest a more realistic example. Fundamentally, [`getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) isn't broken. By the time that callback runs, the script will have been loaded. So look at the browser console, step through the code, etc., etc.

Comment: @user3653474 Did you close the sucess ajax function with `}` ? Or it's forgotten just for this example ?

Comment: @R3tep : i closed it its just an example.

Comment: @user3653474 It's important to make a valid example, without mistake. Like that, peoples trying to help you don't lose time with this mistakes.

Comment: I dont see any issue with code... Adding sample code would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically inject the source javascript inside head tag(if script is meant for global scope) once response is received.

```
var inject = document.createElement('script');
inject.src = baseUrl + 'resources/....javascriptfile.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(inject);
```